# I suggested that he (should) eat

Tags: meaning-in-context

Which one is correct and more natural?
Is there difference in meaning?

> - I suggested that he **should eat** more vegetables.
> - I suggested that he **eat** more vegetables.
> - I suggested that he **ate** more vegetables.

Can we omit "that" word from these sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/using-suggest/

> **Suggest** can also be followed by **that + subject + should + verb**, but in
>   these clauses both **that** and **should** may be omitted, leaving the subject
>   directly after the verb **suggest**.
>
> EXAMPLES:
>
> - He suggests that I should go to New York.
> - He suggests that I go to New York.
> - He suggests I should go to New York.
> - He suggests I go to New York.

The first two sound okay to me!

You can have multiple variants here:

1. I suggested **that he should eat** more vegetables.
2. I suggested **that he eat** more vegetables.
3. I suggested **he should eat** more vegetables.
4. I suggested **he eat** more vegetables.

There is no difference between the first two sentences you've given, but the third sentence definitely has a different meaning.

"I suggested that he ate more vegetables." sounds like "I suggested and he did eat more vegetables" but I'm not exactly sure about it.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of *Present Subjunctive*.

You use it in a *that*-clause(but you can omit the *that*) to express an action or idea is necessary. It takes a bare infinitival(the `plain` form of) verb.

Verbs like *recommend* and *suggest* are usually used to indicate this form.

This contruction is generally more common in American English than British English. In British English, using *should* is preferable(like the first sentence)

The last sentence is correct but you don't emphasize the neccessity of eating more vegetables.